# PHP Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity

Tags: php, domdocument

the problem is this: if I run the script from the console

```
C:\Users\Dima>php C:\wamp\www\shop\index.php "test" 2
```

then there is a bug:

```
PHP Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 802 in C:\wamp\www\rozetka\app.php on line 40
```

index.php

```
if(isset($argv[1]) && isset($argv[1])){
    return new App((string)$argv[1], (int)$argv[2]);
}
```

and if just run in a browser index.php

```
$app = new App('test', 2);
```

so the application works fine, no errors
please help launch the application from the console, and I'm sorry for my english

Comment: Don't know, where you call `loadHTML()`, but I guess something between `new App` and `loadHTML()` is broken. It's hard to tell, without seeing whats happening.

Comment: Hard to tell, but note that `App` and `Application` are two different classes you're instantiating.

Comment: apparently there's an error on line 40 of app.php - pity no one knows what code that is because it's not in the question.

Comment: Thanks corrected, there is one and the class

Comment: upd: now a new bug, but only when I run the console

Comment: Are you sure the `index.php` in the browser *is* working? Could it be that it issues the same warning, but you have errors turned off in the server? BTW, in your command line app, the second argv[1] should probably be argv[2]. For the rest, you likely have a & instead of a &amp; at line 802 of whatever HTML file your app is loading (possibly "test.html"?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably have an HTML file being referenced by "test" that is being used by `new App()`, however that HTML file contains errors. Most likely (almost certain) cause is something like `<a href="sompage.php?foo=bar&cat=fish">Link</a>`. The `&` in the HREF introduces a character entity, but there is no `;` to go with it.